# Como não permitir fechar o modal do twitter-bootstrap clicando fora da área?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Não sei se tem como, mas estou precisando bloquear o fechamento do modal do twitter-bootstrap quando o usuário clica fora da área do elemento, só permitindo fechar o mesmo ao clicar nos botões de fechamento.

Comment: Só para complemento da pergunta: o modal a qual você se refere é esse aqui? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-usage), basta colocar o atributo `data-backdrop="static"` no seu modal:

```html
<div class="modal fade" data-backdrop="static">
    ...
</div>
```

Comment: Já conferi na documentação que é isso mesmo. +1

Comment: Simples assim, me ajudou mesmo e bastava eu ter lido um pouco mais a documentação. E eu achando que seria complicado. Dos males o menor.